# What is the significant of Neutron in an Atom?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, neutrons

I'm interested to know about Neutron in an atom.This question is very difficult for me.I tried to know the answer of the question many time but I didn't find.

Comment: Why is it a problem? What does not make sense to you?

Answer (score 4):

Neutrons are important in the nucleus because they feel the same binding force that protons do, but unlike protons they do not repel each other (or protons) because they have no electrical charge.

This means that a neutron helps bind protons together by acting as a kind of neutral "glue"; in this way you can get two protons to stick together by adding one neutron to the mix, which is enough to overcome the protons' mutual electrical repulsion. Adding a second neutron makes the resulting nucleus even more stable, and you get a helium nucleus.